# Spring kafka consumer lag metric is always 0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-micrometer

we're building a monitoring system for our Spring Boot application using `micrometer`.
Metrics gathered are published to an Elasticsearch instance through `micrometer-registry-elastic`.
Everything is fine, except for:

- `kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag` is always 0, even when I'm sure there's lag on the consumer group
- `kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag_avg` is always 0, even when I'm sure there's lag on the consumer group
- `kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag_max` has a value different from 0 only on the first measurement exposed.

All other metrics such as `kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lead` are correctly set.

Versions involved:

- `spring-boot:2.5.4`
- `micrometer:1.7.3`
- `micrometer-registry-elastic:1.7.3`
- `spring-kafka:2.7.6`
- `kafka-clients:2.7.1`
- `Kafka broker: 2.7.0`

I debugged the entire setup and there's no evidence of error, `MicrometerConsumerListener` is correctly created, even `KafkaClientMetrics`and all the `Sensor`instances. I have no idea what's the problem, we haven't any particular customization and no error logging message.
It seems like there aren't samples with value different from 0 for the metrics above, but I'm pretty sure there's lag on the broker because I verified that through command line tool directly on the broker.

Any thoughts?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are messages arriving in the topics? Also can you provide any code or configurations?

Comment: As stated above, `consumer lag` is increasing in the broker. It means that message are arriving on the topic. Also `kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lead` is greater than 0, which means that consumers are processing records. Sadly i think that none code or configuration could be useful without a proper startup hint on what to provide :) btw everything is autoconfigured via Spring Boot

Comment: Looks like a `kafka-clients` issue - I see it as 0.0 in VisualVM (MBean plugin) too.

Comment: @GaryRussell thank you. May I file an issue to apache-kafka to do some further investigation? Is this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Reporting+Issues+in+Apache+Kafka the proper channel?

Comment: You don't need to ask for my permission; I am not involved with Kafka development.

Comment: @tommaso.normani did you submit the issue? or did you solve your issue some other way? looking at kafka issues I found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5855, which seems similar but turned out being an issue with the app, not with kafka itself, but I am also not confident that lag is always 0

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish I've created a simple test case before submitting the issue, but I can't reproduce the problem. `kafka.consumer.fetch.manager.records.lag` behave as expected, so I'm still working on this problem in my spare time. Atm I've adopted a workaroud with `records-lead`metric

Answer (score 2):

The metric is depending on the consumer property `max.poll.records` which is `500` by default.
If your lag is below 500 the metric will show 0.
To verify if you are affected by this, set the `max.poll.records` to `1` and see if the metrics report a lag.